# GCD - dispatch_async works on main queue but crashes on a background queue

Tags: ios, c, multithreading, macos

Without going into too much detail, I'm toying around with a reasonably complex asymmetric signature algorithm written in C, and calling it from an osx application written in Swift. Signatures take around 1 second, so I'm trying to call it asynchronously.

Async on the main queue works, but running it on the main queue kinda defeats the purpose of running it asyncronously.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
// run code
}
```

Async on a background queue crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
// run code
}
```

Sync on a background queue works, but it locks up the UI (main queue) anyway.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
// run code
}
```

Can anyone explain why running code asynchronously on the main queue works fine, but causes a crash when run on a background queue?  Is there a remedy?  If not, then what is preferable... async on the main queue or sync on a background queue?

Comment: it depends on the very code you run. show us where exactly the crash occurs

Comment: Sync on background queue would block the thread you called it from (that's what "synchronous" means). In terms of why async is crashing, it isn't the asynchronous dispatch that is causing the problem, but rather more likely what you're doing inside that block (or what you're trying to do with the results after the block). As Andrey says, show us what you're doing.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing in the block is signing a message. The algorithm uses about 15 classes... it's not really practical to share code here.  I know it's hard to answer my question without seeing code, but I was looking for more general reasons why code would crash on a background queue as opposed to the main queue.

Comment: Dispatching asynchronously to a background queue could for example cause a crash if both the background queue and the main queue access some non-thread-safe resource (e.g. an array or dictionary) without proper synchronization. It is impossible to answer your question without more detailed information.

Comment: @hunter "It's not really practical to share the code here" ... We really don't want to see all of that code, anyway. But the reality of the situation is that the problem rests in that code, not what you've shared with us thus far. You should construct a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the simplest possible example that manifests the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: @hunter The main reason is that some resource or object was released before async delivery or is used in non-reentrant way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your c code directly from objective c code then you need to wrap up the c code in objective c file and call the that wrapper method from.dispatch queue.